# exit loop pynput thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pynput

Hello i'm trying to make a program to play snake using pynput.
When I press space the program runs but even if I press backspace i can't stop it, I know that I have to use threading but I don't figure how it works, thank you

my code :

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import threading
import time

kb = Controller()

def droite(key):
    kb.press(Key.right)
    kb.release(Key.right)

def gauche(key):
    kb.press(Key.left)
    kb.release(Key.left)

def haut(key):
    kb.press(Key.up)
    kb.release(Key.up)

def bas(key):
    kb.press(Key.down)
    kb.release(Key.down)

def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.space:
        print('yes')
        droite(Key.right)
        time.sleep(1.7)
        haut(Key.up)
        time.sleep(0.9)
        gauche(Key.left)
        time.sleep(2.15)
        bas(Key.down)
        time.sleep(1.9)
        droite(Key.right)
        time.sleep(2.15)
        for i in range(255):
            for i in range(6):
                haut(Key.up)
                time.sleep(0.1 )
                gauche(Key.left)
                time.sleep(2.1)
                haut(Key.up)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                droite(Key.right)
                time.sleep(2.1) 
        gauche(Key.left)
        time.sleep(2.15)
        bas(Key.down)
        time.sleep(1.9)
        droite(Key.right)
           
def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.backspace:
        print('no')
        KeyboardInterrupt
        return False


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

th1 = threading.Thread(target=on_press)
th1.start()
th2 = threading.Thread(target=on_release)
th2.start()

th1.join()
th2.join()
```

I'm trying to stop the program even if I'm in a loop when I press a key